# How do I use scrapy rules to crawl from Wiki actor and movie pages to only the links in the cast and fimlography links

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I have recently started to use python and scrapy.
I have been trying to use scrapy to start at either a movie or actor wiki page, save the name and cast or filmography and traverse through the links in the cast or filmography sections to other actor/movie wiki pages.

However, I have no idea how rules work (edit: ok, this was a bit of hyperbole) and the wiki links are extremely nested. I saw that you can limit by xpath and give id or class but most of the links I want don't seem to have a class or id. I also wasn't sure if xpath also includes the other siblings and children.

Therefore I would like to know what rules to use to limit the non-relevant links and only go to cast and filmography links.

Edit: Clearly, i should have explained my question better. Its not that I dont understand xpaths and rules at all (that was a bit of hyperbole since I was getting frustrated) but I'm clearly not completely clear on their working. Firstly, let me show what I had so far and then clarify where I am having trouble.

```
import logging
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor, re
from scrapy.exceptions import CloseSpider
from Assignment2_0.items import Assignment20Item

logging.basicConfig(filename='spider.log',level = logging.DEBUG)


class WikisoupSpiderSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'wikisoup_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['en.wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keira_Knightley']

rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css= 'table.wikitable')),
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow =('(/wiki/)',), ),
              callback='parse_crawl', follow=True))

actor_counter = 0
actor_max = 250
movie_counter = 0
movie_max = 125

def parse_crawl(self, response):
    items = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    item = Assignment20Item()
    occupations = ['Actress', 'Actor']
    logging.debug(soup.title)

    tempoccu = soup.find('td', class_ = 'role')
    logging.warning('tempoccu only works for pages of people')

    tempdir = soup.find('th', text = 'Directed by')
    logging.warning('tempdir only works for pages of movies')


    if (tempdir is not None) and self.movie_counter < self.movie_max:
        logging.info('Found movie and do not have enough yet')

        item['moviename'] = soup.h1.text
        logging.debug('name is ' + item['moviename'])

        finder = soup.find('th', text='Box office')
        gross = finder.next_sibling.next_sibling.text
        gross_float = re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", gross)
        item['netgross'] = float(gross_float[0])
        logging.debug('Net gross is ' + gross_float[0])

        finder = soup.find('div', text='Release date')
        date = finder.parent.next_sibling.next_sibling.contents[1].contents[1].contents[1].get_text(" ")
        date = date.replace(u'\xa0', u' ')
        item['releasedate'] = date
        logging.debug('released on ' + item['releasedate'])

        item['type'] = 'movie'
        items.append(item)

    elif (tempoccu is not None) and (any(occu in tempoccu for occu in occupations)) and self.actor_counter < self.actor_max:
        logging.info('Found actor and do not have enough yet')

        item['name'] = soup.h1.text
        logging.debug('name is ' + item['name'])

        temp = soup.find('span', class_ = 'noprint ForceAgeToShow').text
        age = re.findall('\d+', temp)
        item['age'] = int(age[0])
        logging.debug('age is ' + age[0])

        filmo = []
        finder = soup.find('span', id='Filmography')
        for x in finder.parent.next_sibling.next_sibling.find_all('i'):
            filmo.append(x.text)
        item['filmography'] = filmo
        logging.debug('has done ' + filmo[0])

        item['type'] = 'actor'
        items.append(item)

    elif (self.movie_counter == self.movie_max and self.actor_counter == self.actor_max):
        logging.info('Found enough data')

        raise CloseSpider(reason='finished')

    else :
        logging.info('irrelavent data')

        pass

    return items
```

Now, my understanding of the rules in my code is it should allow all wiki links and should take links only from table tags and their children. This is clearly not what was happening since it very quickly crawled away from movies.

I'm clear on what to do when each element has an identifier like id or class but when inspecting the page, the links are buried in multiple nests of id-less tags which don't seem to all follow a singular pattern(I would use the regular xpath but different pages have different paths to filmography and it didn't seem like finding the path to the table under h2=filmography, would include all links in the tables below it). Therefore I wanted to know more on how I could get scrapy to only use Filmography links(in actor pages anyway).

I apologize if this was an obvious thing, I have started using both python and scrapy/xpath/css only 48 hours ago.

Comment: @stranac I have clarified my question and added my code to show what I had and why I was unable to proceed. Its not that my code wasn't working (I had tried multiple variation of rules, including one that just crawls all wiki pages with no restrictions), but its too inefficient. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you will need to know where you have to look for, I mean, Which tags you have to filter, so you have to inspect in the HMTL code corresponding on your page. Regarding libraries, I would use:

```
import requests
```

to do the connections

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
```

to parser

example:

```
bs = bs('file with html code', "html.parser")
```

you instance the object
    select_tags = bs('select')
you look for the tags you want to filter

Then you should to wrap your list and add some condition like this:

```
    for i in self.select:
        print i.get('class'), type(i.get('class'))
        if type(i.get('class')) is list and '... name you look for ...' in i.get('class'):
```

In this case you can filter inside the select tag you want by 'class' tag.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want, you will probably need to combine your two rules into one, using both `allow` and `restrict_xpath/restrict_css`.

So, something like:

```
rules = [
    Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=['/wiki/'], restrict_xpaths=['xpath']),
         callback='parse_crawl',
         follow=True)
]
```

Scraping wikipedia is usually pretty complicated, especially if trying to access very specific data.
There are a few problems i see for this particular example:

- The data lacks structure - it's just a bunch of text in sequence, meaning your xpaths are going to be pretty complicated. For example, to select the 3 tables you want, you might need to use:
  `//table[preceding-sibling::h2[1][contains(., "Filmography")]]`
- You only want to follow links from the `Title` column (second one), however, due to the way HTML tables are defined, this might not always be represented by the second `td` of a row.
  This means you'll probably need some additional logic, wither in your xpath, or in your code.
- IMO the biggest problem: the lack of consistency. For examle, take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerard_Butler#Filmography No tables there, just a list and a link to another article. Basically, you get no guarantee about naming, positioning, layout, or display of information.

Those notes might get you started, but getting this information is going to be a big task.

My recommendation and personal choice would be to obtain the data you want from a more specialized source, instead of trying to scrape a website as generalized as wikipedia.